# CSS border cannot display in the right place

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to put a border at the top of this `div` and at the bottom. However, this code causes the border to show underneath the 'title' copy rather than at the end of the `div`.

```
<div style='border-top: solid; border-bottom:solid'>
    <div>
      <p style='margin-left:200px;'>
        <a href="http://www.me.com">Title</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="competition_image" style='margin-left:125px;'>
      <%= image_tag "me.png"%>
    </div>
    <div class="competition_image" style='width: 600px; margin-left:125px;'>
      <%= image_tag "mescreenshot.png"%>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p style='float:left; margin-left: 200px;'>
        <a href="http://www.me.com">Click here to read full article</a>
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: isn't this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/V3Wcw/ (***did not change anything, it's that your code***).

Comment: We should see an example with all the style applied, but if I had to guess, I suspect you have some other floated elements (or with position: absolute)

Comment: Yes King King - you are right, it is obviously something somewhere else in my code.

Comment: I've edited the original post to link to the actual page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you're not clearing your floats :)

```
<div style='border-top: solid; border-bottom:solid'>
    <div>
      <p style='margin-left:200px;'>
        <a href="http://www.me.com">Title</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="competition_image" style='margin-left:125px;'>
      <%= image_tag "me.png"%>
    </div>
    <div class="competition_image" style='width: 600px; margin-left:125px;'>
      <%= image_tag "mescreenshot.png"%>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p style='float:left; margin-left: 200px;'>
        <a href="http://www.me.com">Click here to read full article</a>
      </p>
    </div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

notice the 'clear:both' at the bottom.. should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help. I've added the actual page link to my original post as I guess it's some other part of the css causing the problem and I can't work out what it is

Comment: In the page you linked I only see: <div style='border-top: solid;'>, when I add 'border-bottom', and the div with clear:both like in my example above, I get the result you were looking for

Comment: ok thanks. Yes you are right, this now works. I must have been putting the clear: both; in the wrong place before.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style='border-top: solid; border-bottom:solid; overflow:hidden;'>
```

It's because all those floats, as Eyal pointed. I'd "remake" the whole div not using floats and margins, but centering the divs.

**EDIT**

I'll do it like this:

```
<div style="border-top: solid;text-align: center;border-bottom: solid;">
<div>
  <p>
   <a href="http://www.me.com">Title</a>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="competition_image" style="margin: 0 auto;float: none;">
   <%= image_tag "me.png"%>
</div>
<div class="competition_image" style="float: none;margin: 0 auto;">
  <%= image_tag "mescreenshot.png"%>
</div>
<div>
  <p>
    <a href="http://www.me.com">Click here to read full article</a>
  </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style='border:1px solid red;border-left:1px solid transparent;border-right:1px solid transparent;">
```